# Retrieve date from a table column and make the rows change color depending on the amount of days between today and the date

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm a newbie at javascript and would like to know how would i be able to obtain de date td from every row, calculate the amount of days between that date and the current date, and if the number is bigger than let's say 100, make those rows have a red background. Here's the code:

```
     <html>

<head>


<title>Due Bills</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<script>  

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
    responsive: true
    } );



    $('checkdate').on( {       

        var today = new Date();
        var currDate = today.getDate();
        var date2 = new Date(2015,1,15);
        var timeDiff = Math.abs(currDate.getTime() - date2.getTime());
        var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 

        if(diffDays > 100){

                $("#example tr").css('background-color', '#FF0000');

        }

    } );

} );

</script>


</head>

<body>

    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td class="checkdate">2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td class="checkdate">2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td class="checkdate">2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td class="checkdate">2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Airi Satou</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td class="checkdate">2008/11/28</td>
            <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td class="checkdate">2012/12/02</td>
            <td>$372,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td class="checkdate">2012/08/06</td>
            <td>$137,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td class="checkdate">2010/10/14</td>
            <td>$327,900</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>39</td>
            <td class="checkdate">2009/09/15</td>
            <td>$205,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sonya Frost</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td class="checkdate">2008/12/13</td>
            <td>$103,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jena Gaines</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td class="checkdate">2008/12/19</td>
            <td>$90,560</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
            <td>Support Lead</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td class="checkdate">2013/03/03</td>
            <td>$342,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Charde Marshall</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td class="checkdate">2008/10/16</td>
            <td>$470,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td class="checkdate">2012/12/18</td>
            <td>$313,500</td>
        </tr>




    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
```

Comment: Have you attempted anything yet? Take a look at the w3schools link for [referencing table cells in javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_table_cells.asp)

Comment: Is this table actually static, or is it being generated from a database query? If it is being generated from a query, you could do the date check as part of the query and set the color when outputting the data. If this is truly static, do you have any control over the HTML? If so, adding a class attribute to the cells containing the dates (e.g. <td class="check_date">2012/09/26</td>) may make it easier to find the dates in order to check them. Otherwise, you will have to iterate through each row of the table and locate the 5th cell. By the way, jQuery would be helpful to use for this.

Comment: Thanks for answering, this is a static table that will get its data from a <MGREPEAT> utilizing magic software, so i can do it the way you said. You're saying i can apply a class to the date cell and use jqeury to calculate the difference of days and apply the color?

Comment: I've edited the code to see if i'm going in the right direction but it is still missing a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the table using document.getElementById( ID of table ).

You can then iterate through the rows, get the date value, compute the difference, and alter the table accordingly.

```
    <script>
      var table = document.getElementById("example");
      for(var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i ++) {
        var d = new Date(table.rows[i].cells[4].innerHTML).getTime();
        var difference = new Date().getTime();
        console.log(((difference - d)/86400000) > 100);
        if(((difference - d)/86400000) > 100)
          table.rows[i].style.background = "red";
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I have a problem, when i paste the code inside the document.ready, the datatable styling disappears and nothing happens. I've also tried pasting it outside the document.ready still inside the script.

Comment: I added the code at the end of table in its own script tag. Also, adding the line of code table.rows[i].cells[0].style.background = "red"; in the if statement will also make the name red.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked! A quick question before we finish, whenever i want to add a functionality to the table without damaging the datatable i must put a separate script?

Comment: @AdrianGonzalez I don't think you have to